# Find the bifurcation value given the differential equations

Tags: optimization, bifurcation

Given

$\dot{x} =-2x+y$

$\dot{y} =x^2-y+r$

Where r is a real number. Find the bifurcation values.

The answer is $r=1$ but I don't see how that can be obtained so if someone can help me further I would be grateful.